# soundcloud api python Get list of followers user ids

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

Using python and the soundcloud api, how can I return a list of my followers; their usernames and ids? 
I run

```
   followers = client.get('/me/followers')
   print followers
   for user in followers:
   print " "
   print user.id
   print user.username
```

But that only returns

```
    soundcloud.resource.Resource object at NUMBER
    TypeError: 'Resource' object is not iterable
```

Everything else I try to do works fine, I authenticate and get a token using the username + password login method... But I still only get one resource returned when i try to view followers as opposed to what should be a list of resources
Am i perhaps using the wrong get method?

Answer (score 1):

```
followers = client.get('me/followers').collection
for user in followers:
    print(user.obj['username'],user.obj['id'])
```

or

```
followers = client.get('me/followers').obj["collection"]
for user in followers:
    print(user['username'],user['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from home but try user['id'].

Edit: oups sorry the error is not there.

Alright here's a way to do it that uses an undocumented api but would be just fine:

```
followers = client.get('me/followers.json')
for user in followers:
    print(user.username,user.id)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "TypeError: 'Resource' object is not iterable" error, though the resource number is different.